# mybatis collection Single attribute eg:Sting list Error attempting to get column xxx from result set

Tags: java, mybatis

Error attempting to get column 'pov_pay_voucher' from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'pov_pay_voucher' not found.
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [S0022]; error code [0]; Column 'pov_pay_voucher' not found.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column 'pov_pay_voucher' not found.
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Error attempting to get column 'pov_pay_voucher' from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'pov_pay_voucher' not found.
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [S0022]; error code [0]; Column 'pov_pay_voucher' not found.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column 'pov_pay_voucher' not found.
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)

Comment: Selcome to StackOverflow! Well, your question is missing: the description of what you are doing, what you want to achieve and what kind of help you expect. There is a very small chance to get help if you just copy and paste the error message you get, not even properly formatted - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tour, then https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then make your question to follow the StackOverflow standards.